# Why is it the carousel next button and circle button doesnt work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code of the carousel tutorial that i've got from http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/. The carousel next button and the carousel dotted button doesn't work. I don't know what happen. Please help me about this. I put the image and the red button determines the buttons that doesn't work.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Caption Text</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Caption Text</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Caption Text</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

[Carousel ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTt9.png)

Comment: did you add jquery? here it works: https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/zkxees4e/

Comment: wow.. sorry sir. i am just a begginner :( .. where can i find the jquery sir.

Comment: posted in the answer...and I am a woman (no sir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the step 2 of the [tutorial you linked in the question](http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/) says, you have to add the following tags to add jquery (order matters):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it okay if i will be using old bootstrap ?

Comment: which version of bootstrap??

Comment: sir. may i know how can i use this in offline ?

Comment: connect to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js, save the page via browser then include it